# What does "Warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast" mean in C?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I'm writing a simple function in C whose purpose is to take a 6 bit number, work out the first 3 bits, and based on that, return a "r", "w" or "o".

However, when I compile I get this warning: 'return makes integer from pointer without a cast'. Then, when I run the program, I find that the function is returning a weird character that definitely isn't one of the three I'm after.

What is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Here's my function:

```
char
readorwrite(int opcode)
{
    if (opcode >> 3 == 4) {
        return "r";
    } else if (opcode >> 3 == 5) {
        return "w";
    } else {
        return "o";
    }
}
```

Comment: Neil Butterworth pointed out in a now deleted answer that you should be very wary of mixing bitwise operators such as shift or AND or OR with comparisons such as equality. The shift operators do have a higher precedence than the comparisons; however, I had to go to the precedence table to check that, though, and I'm not a novice in C. There are particular problems when doing bit-masking as well as bit shifting. Were the code presented to me for review, I would request extra parentheses around the shift operation, even though the compiler will handle it exactly as intended.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that "r", "w" and "o" are string constants, which means that their actual type is char[] or char*. That means your function is actually returning s pointer to a zero-terminated string. For single characters, you should use 'r', 'w', and 'o' instead.

Answer (score 4):

You return a `const char *`, ie a pointer to a location in memory where the string "o" is stored when you should be returning a char 'o'